# Trying to recursively binary search strings in c

Tags: c, string, recursion, binary-search

I need to use a binary search to recursively find a target string. The function should return a -1 if it is not found and a positive integer if found but it always returns -1. thanks for the help!

```
int start = 0;
int search;
search = binary_search(strings, target, start, size-1);
if(search == -1)
{
printf("Not in the dataset!");
}
if(search != -1)
{
printf("%s is in the dataset", target);
}

int binary_search(char **strings, char *target, int start_idx, int end_idx)
{
if(end_idx < start_idx)
    {
    return -1;
    }
int middle = ((start_idx + end_idx)/2);
int i;
i = strcmp(target, strings[middle]); 
if(i == 0)
    {
    return middle;
    }
if(i < 0)
    {
    return binary_search(strings, target, start_idx, middle-1);
    }
else
    {
    return binary_search(strings, target, middle+1, end_idx);
    }
}
```

input data:
aden
caden
david
erik
john
mark
matt
mycah
phil
susan

Comment: Please show a complete example, including the input data and the function call. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: FYI, you don't need a pointer-base, start, and end. You can do this with a pointer-base, a length, and some pointer math. It actually makes i easier to grasp (for me anyway).

Comment: Im not sure what you want to do, compare strings inside a string ? or compare array of strings ?

Comment: Also, is the `strings` array sorted?

Comment: What's the question?  Does the code not work?  What is the input, the output, and the expected output?  Please see this guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NPE helluva good question =P

Comment: the strings are sorted, and the problem is that it always returns -1 even when the target is a string in the array of strings.

Comment: Still missing the input data and function call.

Comment: the function call is on line 3 and i just put the input data. it is put into strings[i]

Answer (score 0):

Although binary search is notoriously hard to get right, I don't see any errors in your algorithm as shown. You can still fail (-1) due to various causes that can not be determined based on the information provided.

1) Your source strings list is not actually sorted correctly -- strcmp() uses ASCII comparison, not dictionary comparison, i.e., your source string must be ASCII sorted for bsearch to be valid.

2) Your source strings are not well-formed NUL terminated C strings.

3) The target string does not have an exact match in the source string list. i.e., searching for "bill" will not match "Bill" or "billiard"

Just a note, a recursive bsearch is slower than and uses more memory than a non-recursive solution